# How to pass variable from JSP/Jboss to Apache

Tags: apache, jboss

I'm running Apache  on webservers and Jboss  on appservers, using mod_jk for integration.
I want to run some JSP and return a flag (variable) to Apache. How to do this?

TIA,
Vitaly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJP13 does not support this, but these referenced as future  enhancements in the 
[AJPv13 extensions Proposal](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/ajp/ajpv13ext.html) seem to be what you're looking for:

Quote:

> - context information passed from servlet engine to web server. Part
>     of the configuration of JK, the web server connector, is to indicate
>     to the web server which URI to handle. The mod_jk JkMount directive,
>     told to web server which URI must be forwarded to servlet engine. A
>     servlet engine allready knows which URI it handle and TC 3.3 is
>     allready capable to generate a config file for JK from the list of
>     available contexts.
> - state update of contexts from servlet engine to web server. Big site
>     with farm of Tomcat, like ISP and virtuals hosters, may need to stop a
>     context for admin purposes. In that case the front web server must
>     know that the context is currently down, to eventually relay the
>     request to another Tomcat